# undefined method `secret_key=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, secret-key

I am using devise with Rails 4. I had a problem with some fields not rendering in the user views and I realised it's because of the `attr_accessible` that's not supported any more so I had a look around and came to the conclusion I should use the latest version of the gem (3.0.3).

And that's when the problem appeared:

I cannot run any rails commands now as I am getting the `undefined method 'secret_key=' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)` error **and it's not going away even if I downgrade the gem.**

Rolling back to some previous git commit doesn't solve it, remove the gem and doing a bundle install again doesn't solve it, and I starting to think I should probably start from scratch.

Does anyone know how to walk past this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this setting is only available in the more recent versions of Devise, 3.1.x and above. You should either upgrade the gem to this version or remove that line that references `secret_key=` from your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

Comment: @sebkomianos which one worked for you? The upgrade of them gem or removing the line from the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file?

Comment: @Jadam Removing the line. Are you getting the same error? I haven't encountered the issue ever since.

Comment: @sebkomianos I've not encountered the issue since either.

Comment: For those among us who are a bit slower on the uptake (like me clearly!), "that line", by default, is lines 4-5 of devise.rb, specifically `config.secret_key = "..." \ "..."`